# How can I start and stop audio recording automatically?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am working on recording audio using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) in C#, and I need to start recording automatically and stop it automatically also after 6 seconds. It works as for starting and stopping after 6 seconds, but the audio is repeated, and it seems to enter an infinite loop.

This is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Create a new Timer
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    private WaveFileWriter RecordedAudioWriter = null;
    private WasapiLoopbackCapture CaptureInstance = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mytimer.Interval = 6000; // Set the interval to 1 second.
        mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mytimer_Tick);
        mytimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mytimer.Start();
        string outputFilePath = @"D:\deep\New\Transfare\tf-File\output\out.wav";

        // Redefine the capturer instance with a new
        // instance of the LoopbackCapture class
        this.CaptureInstance = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();

        // Redefine the audio writer instance with the given configuration
        this.RecordedAudioWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilePath, CaptureInstance.WaveFormat);

        // When the capturer receives audio, start writing
        // the buffer into the mentioned file
        this.CaptureInstance.DataAvailable += (s, a) =>
        {
            this.RecordedAudioWriter.Write(a.Buffer, 0, a.BytesRecorded);
        };

        // When the Capturer Stops
        this.CaptureInstance.RecordingStopped += (s, a) =>
        {
            this.RecordedAudioWriter.Dispose();
            this.RecordedAudioWriter = null;
            CaptureInstance.Dispose();
        };
        // Start recording!
        this.CaptureInstance.StartRecording();
        stoprec(sender, e);
    }

  private void stoprec(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      this.CaptureInstance.StopRecording();
      this.mytimer.Enabled = false;
      this.Close();
  }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem you have is regarding the use of the timer.

These two lines have the same effect:

```
mytimer.Enabled = true;
mytimer.Start();
```

Your program sets up the timer to fire the event after 6 seconds. When it fires, you set up the recording, start it and stop it within a few milliseconds.

My suggestion - do not touch the timer. It will fire the event every 6 seconds.

Use a Boolean to know if you are recording or not.
When the event fires the first time, you start the recording and set your boolean accordingly.

When the event fires the second time, you stop the recording and set your boolean accordingly.

You will have a file with the last 6 seconds that were recorded.
If you only want the event to fire once, you can stop the timer after you stop recording. The Timer will not fire the event again and you can shut down the program.

I am not sure if you are setting up the audio recording correctly, but it is clear you are not using the Timer correctly. Try it out with a console program where you write every time the event fires and what your Boolean value is.